# Problem with PHP from 7.0+, $_SESSION[] not working as before

Tags: php

I have a simple login system using PHP `$_SESSION[]`.

The code to check if the user is logged in is

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login-mywebsite']) && !empty($_SESSION['login-mywebsite'])){
    //user is logged in
}
```

However, with PHP 7.1 and so on (7.2, 7.3) it is not working properly.

I've set a test page with this

`var_dump($_SESSION['login-mywebsite']);`

and it says `string(1) "1"` so it's working.

But when I do the same in my header file, it just says `NULL`.

For now I'll use PHP 7.0, but does someone know why this happens? Maybe it's an issue with my server or my files, but maybe they changed something in 7.1+ that I don't know of.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

**Code in the test page:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION['login-mywebsite']);
?>
```

**Code in the header.php file:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $userLogged = (isset($_SESSION['login-mywebsite']) && !empty($_SESSION['login-mywebsite']));

    if($userLogged){
        include 'database.php';
        $db = getDb();

        if(!isset($active)){
            $active = 'home';
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `id` = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['login-mywebsite']]);

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
?>
```

**And then I have a index.php:**

```
if(!$userLogged){ 
    //form to login
} else {
    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

Neither header.php nor index.php show the value of the session (they show null) when using a var_dump, but the test file does.

Comment: Can we see the code in your test page (where it works) and in you header file (where it doesn't)?

Comment: From the [`session_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) documentation page: "**7.1.0** – session_start() now returns FALSE and no longer initializes $_SESSION when it failed to start the session."

Comment: `if(($_SESSION['login-mywebsite'] == TRUE) AND ($_SESSION['login-mywebsite'] == TRUE)){
    //user is logged in
}` try that

Comment: @cfillion that must be it, but why would it fail to start the session?

Comment: maybe you can `echo` its value instead of `var_dump` and let's see what clue you'll get. and also, can we see where you call the header file?

Comment: @alimbaronia why? `var_dump()` outputs **much more** information than `echo`

Comment: Please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the **beginning** of your script. That way we'd probably have more information as to why the session failed to start.